# Composition with different types

Tags: java, composition

I have two Java classes B and C in which both extend from class A (I do not own class A).

```
public class B extends A {…}
public class C extends A {…}
```

I need a list of type „ListItem“ to hold instances of either B or C, but since both (B and C) are already extended, they cannot be further extended by using „ListItem“ as a superclass.

I think the only way to go is with composition („has-a“ relation…).

Since „ListItem“ should never have B AND C (but only one of them), I am planning to create ListItem with 2 constructors and set an appropriated
inner type to reflect if either B or C is being hold.

Is there a better approach to accomplish this? Please see the pseudo code below.

```
public class ListItem {

    private enum elemType {
        TYPE_B, TYPE_C 
    } 

    private final B mBItem;
    private final C mCItem;
    private final elemType mType;

    // used to hold instance of B
    public ListItem(B b) {
        this.mBItem = b;
        this.mType = TYPE_B;
    } 

    // used to hold instance of C
    public ListItem(C c) {
        this.mCItem = c;
        this.mType = TYPE_C;
    }

    // sample method to demonstrate delegation
    private int getAge() {
        int age;

        if (containsB()) {
            age = mBItem.getAge();
        }
        else if (containsC()) {
            age = mCItem.getAge();
        }
        else {…}
        return age;
    }

    private boolean containsB() {
        return (mType == TYPE_B);    
    }

    private boolean containsC() {
        return (mType == TYPE_C);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't your `ListItem` just hold an `A`? Then you can use `item instanceof B` or `item instanceof C` if you need to test. Although even that's a bit of a red flag; if you're adding some functionality to `A` that is common to `B` and `C` consider deriving some class from `A` to add the common stuff, derive `B` and `C` from that, and make your `ListItem` store that base.

Comment: I cleaned up the example... sorry for A/B/C switches...

Comment: So, in your example, `B` and `C` independently implement `getAge`? It is not a part of `A`? And also, do they implement them differently at all, or exactly the same?

Comment: What about _"I need a list of type „ListItem“ to hold instances of either B or C"_. Why not create a `List<B>` or `List<C>` then, instead of `List<ListItem>`

Comment: @JornVernee getAge() can be different based on the type... as for the second question: both item types can occur in different orders (multiple times...) - so having both types in dedicated lists and merging them seems difficult to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean, you have:

```
public class B extends A {…}
public class C extends A {…}
```

So you could just make your item hold an `A`:

```
public class ListItem {

    private final A item;

    public ListItem (A item) { 
        this.item = item; 
    }

}
```

And you have any number of options on how to handle it from there, e.g. simply:

```
    public A getItem () {
        return item;
    }
```

And do any appropriate casts or tests from the caller. That's the most flexible way. Or I suppose something like:

```
    public B getB () {
        return item instanceof B ? (B)item : null;
    }

    public C getC () {
        return item instanceof C ? (C)item : null;
    }
```

But that's starting to get sloppy, and limits you from storing any other `A`-derived stuff in your `ListItem`.

You might want to start questioning your design here. For example, if you're adding some functionality to `A` that is common to `B` and `C` *and necessary for the proper operation of a `ListItem`*, consider deriving some class from `A` to add the common stuff, derive `B` and `C` from that, and make your `ListItem` store that base (of course, if you do this you can't store an `A` any more):

```
public class AgedA extends A {
    ...
    public int getAge () { return ... }
}

// Then your B and C both extend AgedA, and your ListItem stores an
// AgedA and can use getAge().
```

You could make `AgedA` be abstract and `getAge()` be virtual, if that's more appropriate. Or you could declare an interface that defines `getAge()` and use that.

Yet another option is you could (as pointed out in comments) make `ListItem` be either an interface, or [a class that extends `A`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39215854/616460), then have your `B` and `C` implement or extend that.

I suppose you could also [use generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39215744/616460) for `ListItem` e.g. `<? extends A>`, although that may not be appropriate especially if your `ListItem`s are mixed. The major benefit of using generics is that e.g. getters can now directly return the subtypes without casts and you give yourself compile-time ability to restrict types to a specific subtype in function parameters and stuff, but otherwise it's essentially the same as just storing an `A`.

In any case, aside from the advice to just store `A` in `ListItem` and handle different types at a higher level, I can't in good conscience give you any other approach suggestions, because the need for all of this seems questionable to me.

Comment: The true solution here is to make an abstract class ListItem that extends A, then extend B and C from the ListItem.

Comment: @Purag Yeah, or that if it makes sense. There's definitely better solutions.

Comment: Why is creating an abstract class in the middle better than just extending A?

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey Can't really say if it's "better" or "worse" because we don't really know what a `ListItem` is for, the OP presumably just trimmed it way down in their example. So, that question has no answer. It's just more options. In any case I've added that to the list of options.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey Shared behavior that `A` doesn't contain would be implemented in the abstract class, and `B`/`C` could have their unique implementations of abstract methods that need to be exposed as the interface for an `A`. Of course, an abstract class isn't needed if `B` and `C` won't have any unique behavior, but then why are they disjoint classes to begin with?

Comment: @JasonC thanks for your idea! holding A seems obvious thats true but I want to mention, that I do not own A and thus have no real control over changes in this class... I have to think about the alternatives - but thanks!

Comment: @JoeFrizz Ok, so, something's off here. It shouldn't matter if you have no control over `A`. It just needs to exist, and your `B` and `C` just need to extend it. If an uncontrolled change in `A` breaks your `ListItem`, then chances are it breaks your `B` and `C` too and you've got a more fundamental issue. In that case consider deriving something from `A` with the new functionality, or wrapping `A` in something if that's more appropriate, or making an interface that `B` and `C` implement in addition to extending `A` and use that interface in your `ListItem`, or whatever.

Comment: @JasonC thanks for your help and all clarifications! I try to implement one of the outlined solutions - I think that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think a clean approach to this is to have your `ListItem` be an abstract class extending from `A`, then have `B` and `C` extend from `ListItem`.

Why make `ListItem` abstract? Any behavior that is shared across `B` and `C` can be implemented in the abstract class, and you can additionally impose interfaces requirements on its subclasses.

```
public abstract class ListItem extends A {
    public int getAge () {
        // Both B and C share this implementation
    }

    // But B and C behave differently for this method
    public abstract void manipulate ();
}

public class B extends ListItem {
    public void manipulate () {
        // Something specific to B here.
    }
}

public class C extends ListItem {
    public void manipulate () {
        // Something specific to C here.
    }
}
```

Then you can declare your list of `ListItem`s, insert instances of `B` and `C` as necessary, and manipulate them according to the concrete methods or the abstract interface in `ListItem`:

```
ArrayList<ListItem> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new B());
list.add(new C());

System.out.println(list.get(0).getAge());
list.get(1).manipulate();
```

Comment: That looks like a good, clean solution. Does this solution minimize the fear of having uncontrollable changes in A (do not own) breaking my implementation?

Comment: @JoeFrizz Yes. As with *all* of these solutions, actually (but this is a particularly good one), the only changes to `A` that break your implementation are things in `A` that you directly rely on, like if you call a member function of `A` that gets removed, or some invariant changes and breaks your logic somewhere. But none of that is solvable by your `ListItem` implementation choice here, it's virtually unrelated to the organizational decision you are facing. Your concerns about changes to `A` are not necessarily misplaced, but aren't really relevant to your `ListItem` setup.

Comment: Like mentioned in the other answer, if a change to `A` breaks your list, that means it broke `B` and `C`. If something changes in A, though, any of these solutions will let you "reimplement" it as functionality of `ListItem`.

Comment: In general, it's very hard to protect yourself against changes to interfaces you rely on. This is why, when an API is going to change in a breaking way, they notify users far in advance so they can prepare to update their code.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for all your detailed answers and helpful explanations

Answer (score 0):

From your description it looks like `ListItem` is a container for items of type A (B or C, other sub classes in the future). I would recommend using generics, using `<? extends A>`, you wouldn't then need the more than one constructor and all of A's methods should be available.